# Adobe Flex Mobile Background Process

Tags: java, apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex4, adobe

What is the best solution for multi threading in flex, I notice if I play a mp3 in flex and do something else at the same time something ends up giving out, either the song stops playing or the UI hangs for about a split second.  It doesn't have that fluid response that I am looking to achieve.  If possible I would like to call a multi threaded java class to do some of the client-side end back end processing.  I just don't know if that is possible.  Any insight would be greatly appreciated I am stuck on this one.

-Phil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flex/Flash alone don't support multithreading - Adobe keeps argumenting that multithreading is not necessary for most of potential flex applications and would just increase complexity for the average flex developer too much.

Looking for solutions myself I have only found snippets where the task to be done simultanously gets logically cut into smaller pieces, then you run them piece by piece, letting UI get time slices in between. It might work for some but is no solution to your problem.

Now to Java - using the native process api could make it work. Java process would take over some part of the processing and you would control its working writing to and reading from input/output streams which gets connected between java process and flex app. Another possibility could be inter-process socket communication (did it myself before native process api was there - works!)

Answer (score 0):

If the UI is hanging you have another issue. It seems to me like you are looping through some sort of data to make this "lag". What you can do is format the data better so you don't run into this. Or look into your process that you run when the hanging happens and optimize it better.

Answer (score 0):

Flex/Flash has no blocking methods and so doesn't need threading, just call a function on a timer or enterframe, and make sure it yields in under 25ms or so. As for speed, Java (running in Android's 'Dalvik' VM ) is not a lot better... C is the only option for ultimate speed.

Comment: Internally it uses threads, of course - rendering of the screen will be split equally among cores. However on the actionscript side, asynchronous methods mean that there is technically no use case that *demands* threads... except I suppose using multiple cores to execute actionscript - however, in my experience, script execution is very rarely the bottleneck in flash apps. Good point though. What I meant, I suppose, is that the API is designed with the fact there are no threads available,

Answer (score 0):

Here is a rather complete 'Greean Thread' lib - http://blog.generalrelativity.org/actionscript-30/green-threads/

I have found it useful, as irrespective of Tom's views Threading is most definitely often a needed things that is not supported properly (yet??)

Answer (score 0):

Also bear in my mind that the debug player behaves very differently from the standard player, and (a separate issue) that during a debug session, significant slowdowns can be apparent with performance critical code... Only believe the browser plugin, non-debug version, running in a browser, not debugging. That is the only reliable test. I have seen speed up of 25-30x  just by changing to the release player (extreme case). Thought I had a major performance problem, but actually didn't :)